# phpbb code updation preg_replace to preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, preg-replace, phpbb, preg-replace-callback

I couldn't understand the new php function to use preg_replace_callback instead of preg_replace

I need to convert the following function into new format.

Many thanks in advance

```
$text = preg_replace("#\[\/?[a-z0-9\*\+\-]+(?:=(?:&quot;.*&quot;|[^\]]*))?(?::[a-z])?(\:$uid)\]#", ' ', $text);


preg_replace('#^([^ ]*)#', '', utf8_substr($text, $i - $sequence_length, $sequence_length));


  $match = get_preg_expression('bbcode_htm');
        $replace = array('\1', '\1', '\2', '\1', '', '');

    $message = preg_replace($match, $replace, $message);


$text = preg_replace("#\[\/?[a-z0-9\*\+\-]+(?:=(?:&quot;.*&quot;|[^\]]*))?(?::[a-z])?(\:$uid)\]#", ' ', $text);


preg_replace('/[&?]sid=[0-9a-f]{32}$/', '', preg_replace('/([&?])sid=[0-9a-f]{32}&/', '$1', $relative_url));

preg_replace($magic_url_match, $magic_url_replace, $text);
return preg_replace($censors['match'], $censors['replace'], $text);     
return preg_replace('#<!\-\- s(.*?) \-\-><img src="\{SMILIES_PATH\}\/.*? \/><!\-\- s\1 \-\->#', '\1', $text);
return preg_replace('#<!\-\- s(.*?) \-\-><img src="\{SMILIES_PATH\}\/(.*?) \/><!\-\- s\1 \-\->#', '<img src="' . $phpbb_root_path . $config['smilies_path'] . '/\2 />', $text);
```

Comment: Why do you need to convert? You have to use preg_replace_callback if you were using /e operator. But you didn't use it. Could you explain your problem?

Comment: I have an old forum of phpbb with version 3.0.8 which have the old php function which are no more in use. I am also unable to upgrade my forum version to 3.2.0 by any mean so I decided to change the old function with the new one. thats why I posting these code which are causing errors.

Comment: To my knowledge, `preg_replace` remain in use [link](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace.php). This function will only trigger error if you're using `/e` operator. If you have a look on the 3.2.0 source code, you could see the exactly same function. [Here is search results of the preg_function in source code](https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=preg_replace) Some webhosters disable `preg_replace` function. Could you verify that this is not a limitation of your webhoster? Could you provide us the errors your are mentionning and your PHP version? Thank you!